# Unable to call AJAX listener method, when I clicked on button in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have a command button like below

```
<h:commandButton id ="shoutOOut_button"
                 value="Child Shout Out Settings"
                 onclick="ShoutOutEdit.show(); return false">
    <f:ajax listener="#{settingsBean.gettingSosData()}" immediate="true"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

I tried to call method `gettingSosData()` using AJAX but when I clicked on button AJAX listener method is not invoked.

Comment: You have tagged the question with primefaces, but you are not using any primefaces components or tags. Is this intentional? Otherwise, you can find the solution at the primefaces showcase site.

Comment: I removed primefaces tag,Please let me know where did i mistake in above code